# Can't ask for or couldn’t ask for what to use in this following context? Is this phrase Couldn't ask for has any particular grammar rule?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I could not/ can not ask for more when i've been with my best buddy for such a long time.

Comment: I edit my question.

Comment: 'I cannot ask for a better friend' and 'I could not ask for a better friend' are both grammatical; the latter is more normal (probably because it distances the implied askee).